# Condition based on nth row above or below current row - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replicate something similar to the "Multi Row Formula" tool in Alteryx. I am currently reading a csv file and would like to be able to set a value in a list if the value of another row in the same tested column is true.

Sample Data

```
**Country**
China
India
Brazil
Indonesia
```

When it loops through the row containing Brazil, "Y" should be appended into the new list since China is two rows above. "N" should be appended for the rest.

```
import pandas as pd

csv_in = pd.read_csv('C:/sample.csv')

kind = []                           

for row in csv_in['Country']:
    if ***two rows above this row*** == 'China':
        kind.append('Y')
    elif ***one row below this row*** == 'Canada':
        kind.append('Y')
    else:
        kind.append("N")

csv_in['Result'] = kind
```

I am having trouble finding anything specific to this issue. Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:** I realized I need to do a little more in addition to what I asked initially.

```
  for row in csv_in['Country']:
      if  'hina' in ***two rows above this row***:
          kind.append('Y')
      elif ***one row below this row***.startswith('Can'):
          kind.append('X')
      else:
          kind.append("N")
```

Comment: It somehow reads clumsy to iterate over an indexable structure like a pandas dataframe and then use offsets for two special cases as condition to build element wise a boolean sequence with the same length and implicit 1 to 1 mapping between the positions in both "lists". It should be clearer to prepare a Falsy or 'N' list in one shot based on the length of the dataframe 'Country' column length and find the special case indices of the dataframe and set the offset 2 rows below and 1 above respectively to True or 'y'. ... as now @root has already put into an answer ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to build a Boolean array of where the `'Y'` values should appear, then use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to create the column:

```
import numpy as np

y_cond = (csv_in.shift(2) == 'China') | (csv_in.shift(-1) == 'Canada')
csv_in['Result'] = np.where(y_cond, 'Y', 'N')
```

If you have more than one column in your DataFrame, you'll need to use `csv_in['Country'].shift()` instead of the shorter notation in the code above.

The resulting output on some slightly expanded sample data:

```
     Country Result
0      China      N
1      India      N
2     Brazil      Y
3  Indonesia      N
4     Bhutan      N
5     Mexico      Y
6     Canada      N
7       Peru      N
8   Honduras      N
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to assign non-binary values, I'd take a slightly different approach.

Begin by initializing the results as `'N'`.  For each condition, create a Boolean array similarly as before, and use `loc` to assign the desired value.  Do this in reverse order of importance, as subsequent matches will overwrite previous ones.

Note that you can use the `.str` accessor to apply string functions to a column, as described in the [Working with Text Data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) section of the documentation.

```
csv_in['Result'] = 'N'

x_cond = csv_in['Country'].shift(-1).str.startswith('Can').fillna(False)
csv_in.loc[x_cond, 'Result'] = 'X'

y_cond = csv_in['Country'].shift(2).str.contains('hina').fillna(False)
csv_in.loc[y_cond, 'Result'] = 'Y'
```

The `.fillna(False)` is necessary as `loc` needs purely Boolean values, and `shift` introduces `NaN` values.  If you really want to write your conditions in order of importance, you could do something like `x_cond & (csv_in['Result'] == 'N')` inside of `loc`, although it might hinder performance.

Updated output:

```
     Country Result
0      China      N
1      India      N
2     Brazil      Y
3  Indonesia      N
4     Bhutan      N
5     Mexico      X
6     Canada      N
7       Peru      N
8   Honduras      N
```

Comment: Thanks! This did exactly what I asked! But I am an idiot, what If I wanted Canada to return "X" instead. What if I wanted to use startswith() or "in". I receive this error:  'series object has no attribute startswith'. I updated my clumsy code. Sorry about that!